# Wordpress Jquery+scripts enqueue issue

Tags: functions, jquery, wp-enqueue-script

I'm having some issues in loading a custom jquery slider into a wordpress site I'm working on: I'm not super proficient with theme development but I'm studying hard and I spent lots of days trying with no result.

I'm using the beaver builder for the graphical aspect but I'd like to insert a content slider (which in the free version is not provided). I tried to use a ready jquery content slider called anyslider.

My issue is that I'm not sure I'm loading the jquery scripts properly: thi is how I edited the functions.php file of my child theme:

```
<?php

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts' ,'enqueue_parent_theme_style' );

function enqueue_parent_theme_style() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'parent-style', get_template_directory_uri().'/style.css' );

if (!is_admin()) add_action("wp_enqueue_scripts", "my_jquery_enqueue", 11);

function my_jquery_enqueue() {
   wp_deregister_script('jquery');
   wp_register_script('jquery', "http" . ($_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'] == 443 ? "s" : "") . "://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js", false, null);
   wp_enqueue_script('jquery');

function add_my_script() {
  wp_enqueue_script(
    'anyslider',
    get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/jquery.anyslider.js', 
    array('jquery')
  );

  wp_enqueue_script(
    'anyslider_easing',
    get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/jquery.easing.1.3.js',
    array('jquery','anyslider')                     
  );
} 

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'add_my_script' );
```

I tried to follow every tutorial I found by the book what am i doing wrong?

EDIT

I edited the functions.php file like this: now it's working, thanks everybody

```
<?php

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts' ,'enqueue_parent_theme_style' );

function enqueue_parent_theme_style() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'parent-style', get_template_directory_uri().'/style.css' );
}


if( !is_admin() ){
    wp_deregister_script('jquery');
    wp_register_script('jquery', ("http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"), false, '');
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
}



add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'mytheme_custom_scripts');

if (wp_script_is('jquery')) echo "<h1>IT WORKS!</h1>";
```

Comment: There are some closing brackets missing and you're loading an old jquery version, but otherwise your code looks fine. Could you describe what exactly is the problem you are experiencing?

Comment: Yes, sorry: I tried to troubleshoot it. 
I added an alert window script wich is working (so I'm quite sure at least a basic version of jquery is running). when i set up the html an css markup on my page and try to call it with its function the slider doesn't work at all (I'm using the following slider as a template

https://jwilsson.github.io/AnySlider/

The thing I'm not sure of is if the other two scripts are loading or not.

Comment: Depending on how you call it `alert()` wil also work in plain javascript without jquery. I'd double check that. Are you sure the enqueued scripts work with the jquery version you load? You could also try [`wp_script_is`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_script_is)

Comment: you really do not need the `my_jquery_enqueue` function at all, where did that come from..? you should let wordpress enqueue jquery unless you have a very very specific reason and even then it's not the best idea...

Comment: i found the my_jquery_enqueue here: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/wordpress/include-jquery-in-wordpress-theme/. (anyways I removed it it) I also corrected the jquery version: now it's 2.2.4. Script still not running. I found and corrected the missing brackets but nothing.

Comment: Right now, inspecting the page with firebug shows me that the scripts I need are called in the header. the scripts I tried are working on the demo I downloaded and I'm trying to adapt them to the wordpress site.
I'm working on with no results. If i put the code in a static website markup (with the latest version of jquery and the scripts) It's working so i suspect it's not a matter of script versions.
this is the function I'm using to call the script https://jsfiddle.net/bonko/7fh215e9/ @cjbj: I read the codex: I'm not really sure about how I should use the wp_script_is. I'll inquire further

Comment: You can use `if (wp_script_is('anyslider')) echo "done anyslider";` after `wp_enqueue_script` to make sure the enqueueing succeeded.

Comment: Useful! I did it and echoes "sone anyslider" I guess the problem is elsewhere. I'm trying to understand if the issue might be the script not being below the slider

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The enqueue_parent_theme_style() and my_jquery_enqueue() functions do not have closing brackets. Does the above code run?

Otherwise the code looks okay.
Are running WordPress with WP_DEBUG set to true?
https://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress
I use the following in my wp-config.php file:

```
if ($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] == '123.456.789.123') {
    define('WP_DEBUG', true);
    define('WP_DEBUG_LOG', true);
    define('WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY', false);
    @ini_set('display_errors', 0);
}
else {
    define('WP_DEBUG', false);
}
```

Comment: First of all, thanks for the debugging tip: very useful. To answer to your question: The debugging log is empty (no errors).

Can you explain me better the following statement?

"The enqueue_parent_theme_style() and my_jquery_enqueue() functions do not have closing brackets."

I'm not sure about where in the code this error occurs (Sorry I'm a newbie and I'm not so familiar yet with the syntax)

Comment: he is saying every `{` opening a function definition must be closed with `}` or the php syntax will fail giving you a fatal error... you are missing two.